# Connecting non-db, non-rest loopback connector to Loopback 4

Tags: loopbackjs

Hoping someone can help me understand some Loopback 4 basics...

I'd like to connect a loopback connector that doesn't connect to a database or a REST endpoint. This particular library sends email using the sendgrid library. It's just basically a send function wrapped by a connector.

I'm not sure how to expose this function to my controller so that I can send emails, as the datasources require either 1. CRUD commands 2. REST endpoints, which doesn't apply to this connector.

I'm completely new to Loopback 4, so maybe I am just missing some basic knowledge which I can't find. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This particular library sends email using the sendgrid library. It's just basically a send function wrapped by a connector.
>   I'm not sure how to expose this function to my controller

Please follow the instructions in [Calling other APIs and web services](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Calling-other-APIs-and-web-services.html). Essentially:

1. Create a datasource for your sendgrid connector using [`lb4 datasource`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/DataSource-generator.html). Edit the created datasource JSON file and provide the necessary configuration like client credentials.
2. Create a new Service using [`lb4 service`](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Service-generator.html) command.
3. Modify your controller - inject the Service via constructor arguments.

   ```
   constructor(
     @inject('services.EmailService')
     protected emailService: CalculatorService,
   ) {}
   ```
4. In the controller methods, call the method provided by the connector via the injected service instance.

Alternatively, you don't have to use the connector and can call sendgrid library directly from your controller methods.

Comment: Thanks @miroslav. I tried this, but when I run the `lb4 service` command, it doesn't list my sendgrid datasource. The service generator seems to expect a REST datasource. I confirmed this by creating a REST datasource, which it did recognize. How can I connect the sendgrid connector to it? [Here](https://github.com/VMois/loopback-sendgrid-connector) is the connector I'm using.

Comment: This looks like an oversight on our side. Essentially, we use metadata about known connectors (see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-workspace/blob/master/available-connectors.json) to decide whether the connector backing each datasource announces "Model" as the base class and thus is "service"-like. Obviously, that does not work for connectors we are not aware of. Can you open a new GitHub issue please? Preferably a "feature request" - see https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/new/choose

Comment: I have created the feature request [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/3288)

Thanks for your help with this. So it sounds like currently the only working alternative would be just to import the library directly into my controllers as you mentioned, is that correct?

Comment: Not really. I believe you can provide the datasource name as a command-line argument to `lb4 service` command, then it will skip the base-model check and use the provided datasource.